# Consistency in tag transliteration

Tags: discussion, tags

There is some inconsistency with tag names. Most of them are spelled according to sefaradi pronunciation like [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) etc., but a few of them have ashkenazi pronunciation like [beis-hamikdash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beis-hamikdash) and [shemos-sacred-names](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shemos-sacred-names).

I also think a few of them have teimani spellings (i.e. th for ת) although I haven't found any of those in my brief search.

Do we want to be consistent with transliterations, or are we saying that it's not such a big deal?

Comment: oops, apparently [I already asked this question](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/inconsistent-spelling-of-tags) which was [already a duplicate.](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/679/unified-transliteration-convention-for-tags)

Comment: I guess this bothers you a great deal. I think one thing we/you should consider doing is suggesting synonyms for any high-profile tags that use one of multiple possible transliterations and don't already have synonyms for the other transliterations.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I started to do that, but unfortunately I have an insufficient score in many of those tags to suggest synonyms

Comment: we could create a Meta post that lists such requests to moderators.